'ERROR [HttpExceptionFilter] Maximum call stack size exceeded' when implement schema using mongoose in NestJS
I'm using NestJS. I'm making a schema for my mongodb, the schema looks like this:
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from "@nestjs/mongoose";
import { ProductInCartDto } from "../dtos/product-in-cart.dto";

@Schema({ collection: 'carts', timestamps: true })
export class Cart {
    @Prop()
    userId: number;

    @Prop()
    products: ProductInCartDto[];

}

export const CartSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Cart);

The ProductInCartDto looks like this:
export class ProductInCartDto {

    storeId: number;

    productList: {[productId: number]: number}[];
    
}

This is the model I used to test the schema:
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Cart } from '../domains/schemas/cart.schema';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';

@Injectable()
export class CartModel {
    constructor(@InjectModel(Cart.name) private cartModel: Model<Cart>) {}
    
    async createCart() {
        return await this.cartModel.create({ 
            userId: 1,
            products: [{
                storeId: 1,
                productList: {
                    1: 1,
                    2: 2
                }
            }]
        });
    }
}

When I execute the model, it return the following error:
[Nest] 33570  - 06/24/2024, 9:14:36 PM   ERROR [HttpExceptionFilter] Maximum call stack size exceeded
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at MetadataStorage.getExposedProperties (/home/long/vegeta/HealthyFoodApplication_BackEnd/node_modules/src/MetadataStorage.ts:115:23)
    at TransformOperationExecutor.getKeys (/home/long/vegeta/HealthyFoodApplication_BackEnd/node_modules/src/TransformOperationExecutor.ts:461:54)
    at TransformOperationExecutor.transform (/home/long/vegeta/HealthyFoodApplication_BackEnd/node_modules/src/TransformOperationExecutor.ts:150:25)
    at TransformOperationExecutor.transform (/home/long/vegeta/HealthyFoodApplication_BackEnd/node_modules/src/TransformOperationExecutor.ts:327:31)
    at TransformOperationExecutor.transform (/home/long/vegeta/HealthyFoodApplication_BackEnd/node_modules/src/TransformOperationExecutor.ts:32

However, the data record is still added to the mongodb database regardless of the error. Also I figured out that this error only occur when there is an property of array in the schema (ProductInCartDto[] in this case). If I don't use array, the error will disappear
What can be the cause here?
I tried changing data structure of ProductInCartDto but it doesn't work. I can't remove the array of ProductInCartDto[] since this property need to be an array

according to Maximum call stack size exceeded error, your DTO is not a standard DTO which is nested function, beside that, its not good way to defined Maps in mongoose
if you want to do this:
  {
     userId: 1,
     products: [{
            storeId: 1,
            productList: {
                 1: 1,
                 2: 2
                }
           }]
   }

you must FIRST define Product:
@Schema()
export class Product {
    @Prop({ required: true })
    storeId: number;

    @Prop({ type: Map, of: Number })
    productList: Map<number, number>;
}

Then Carts
@Schema({ collection: 'carts', timestamps: true })
export class Cart {
    @Prop({ required: true })
    userId: number;

    @Prop({ type: [ProductSchema], default: [] })
    products: Product[];
}

insert a Mock Data
  return await this.cartModel.create({
            userId: 1,
            products: [
                {
                    storeId: 1,
                    productList: new Map([
                        [1, 1],
                        [2, 2],
                    ]),
                },
            ],
        });


I tried your solution but new error arised:
ERROR [HttpExceptionFilter] Cart validation failed: products.0.productList: Cast to Map failed for value "Map(2) { 1 => 1, 2 => 2 }" (type Map) at path "productList" because of "TypeError"
As far as I know, this is due to mongoose being unable to cast the 'Map' object

i show you the right way, you must solve the becoming problems...
